# Can anybody recommend a book on quantum physics for a mathematically minded student?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

Basically what the title says. I'm a math/physics double major going into my second year, but I'm much more math oriented. I'll be taking a quantum class in the fall and I'd like a book that approaches the topic from a rigorous mathematical standpoint. If it matters at all, I have a good understanding of linear algebra, abstract algebra, differential equations, and some analysis.

Comment: My advice: stick to mathematical books. For the "standard" approach to QM I would recommend the book by Hall "Quantum theory for mathematicians", or the encyclopaedic "Methods of modern mathematical physics" by Reed and Simon (4 volumes, some parts of the first and the second should suffice for the basis). For the $C^*$ algebraic approach, I would recommend the books by Bratteli and Robinson (that however are quite technical) or as an overview the chapter on operator algebras of the "noncommutative geometry" book by Connes (also some parts of the introduction).

Comment: In my opinion the **"Quantum Mechanics"** (Vol 1+2) by **Claude Cohen-Tannoudji**, Bernard Diu and Frank Laloe is the best book out there for undergraduate quantum mechanics courses. It covers every corner of the subject with very rigorous approuch. The single downside is it's length, but if you cover it all - you'll get a very good understanding of the topics.

Comment: Yep, Cohen-Tannoudji is great. I like Sakurai a lot as well.

Comment: If you try to understand QM from the math side only you won't understand QM. You need to understand the phenomenology, as well.